# How to find the value which is closest to the series 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, ...?

Tags: java

I'd like to obtain the value closest to the following series :

`1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, ...`

By "closest to x" I mean "the largest value in the series that is less than or equal to x". We can assume x is always greater than or equal to 1.

Eg:

```
1 : 1
2 : 1
9 : 5
10 : 10
27 : 10
33 : 10
49 : 10
52 : 50
86 : 50
```

It's relatively easy to do the same with powers of 10 (`1, 10, 100, 1000, ...`) :

```
int closestTo10(int value) {
    return (int)Math.pow(10.0, Math.floor(Math.log10(value)));
}
```

I'm struggling to do the same the series given above.

Possible idea: take value which is closest to `5, 50, 500, 5000, 50000, ...` (I am not sure how to)

Then take the larger of the two: `Math.max(closestTo5(value), closestTo10(value))`.

Comment: How would you do it if you were doing it by hand?

Comment: Hint: write down what numbers "collapse" to 1, which ones "collapse" to 5, 10, ... So just write down the numbers from let's say 1 to 20 and then from 70 to 90 and underneath each write down what it maps to. See if you can spot a pattern.

Comment: @DaveNewton : I would like to prevent using a loop and rather do it mathematically (if possible)

Comment: @tigrou - You are over-thinking it.  This is a programming site, not a mathematics puzzle site.  :-)

Comment: check/compare the results of `log10(5)`, `log10(50)`, `log10(500)`, ... Another approach, what would happen if we first divide `x` by `5`, call `closestTo10()`  and multiply the result by `5` (basically a result of first point and some maths)

Comment: Are you allowed to use [Arrays.binarySearch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int%5B%5D,int))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Mathematic

Using your own solution, which will work for 1, 10, 100, 1000, ...:

`(int) Math.pow(10.0, Math.floor(Math.log10(value)))`

we can change it, so it works with 5, 50, 500, 5000, ... by dividing the input parameter by 5 and multiplying the result with 5:

`(int) Math.pow(10.0, Math.floor(Math.log10(value/5.0))) * 5.0`

<sup>(multiplying with 2 and then dividing by 2 would also work)</sup>

These must be combined by taking the greater value of both:

```java
import static java.lang.Math.*;

int closestTo5And10(int value) {
    return (int) max(
        pow(10, floor( log10(value) )),
        pow(10, floor( log10(value / 5.0) )) * 5.0
        );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```java
public class Puzzle {

    private static int sequenceGenerator(int index) {
        var num = 1;
        if (index == 0) {
            return num;
        } else {
            for (int i = 1; i <= index; ++i) {
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    num *= 5;
                } else {
                    num *= 2;
                }
            }
        }

        return num;
    }

    private static int findValueClosestTo(int target) {
        var index = 0;

        while (sequenceGenerator(index) <= target) {
            ++index;
        }
        return sequenceGenerator(index - 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var testValues = List.of(1, 2, 9, 10, 27, 33, 49, 52, 86);

        testValues.forEach(num -> {
            System.out.printf("sequence value matching %s = %s%n", num, findValueClosestTo(num));
        });
    }
}
```

It's not the most elegant solution, but it seems to work. If you run it, it prints:

```
sequence value matching 1 = 1
sequence value matching 2 = 1
sequence value matching 9 = 5
sequence value matching 10 = 10
sequence value matching 27 = 10
sequence value matching 33 = 10
sequence value matching 49 = 10
sequence value matching 52 = 50
sequence value matching 86 = 50
```

Answer (score 1):

How about iterate through the series and calculate the absolute difference between each element and the target number? something like this:

```
public int findClosestValue(int target) {
    int[] series = {1, 5, 10, 50, 100, ...}; // ...
    int closestValue = series[0];
    int minDiff = Math.abs(target - series[0]);

    for (int num : series) {
        int diff = Math.abs(target - num);
        if (diff < minDiff) {
            minDiff = diff;
            closestValue = num;
        }
    }

    return closestValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a loop to generate the series, the closed-form of the nth term is:

```
private static long getSeriesValue(final int forTerm) {
    if (forTerm % 2 == 0) {
        return 5L * (long)Math.pow(10, (forTerm - 1) / 2);
    } else {
        return (long)Math.pow(10, forTerm / 2);
    }
}
```

When looking for the closest series value <= `x`, consider how many digits are in `x`.  This can be used to limit the range of series values that need to be checked to at most 3:

```
private static long getClosestSeriesValueLessThanOrEqualTo(int x) {
    var minTerm = (int) Math.log10(x) * 2;
    var maxTerm = minTerm + 2;
    for(var t = maxTerm; t >= minTerm; t--) {
        var seriesValue = getSeriesValue(t);
        if (seriesValue <= x) {
            return seriesValue;
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot determine the closest series value");
}
```

so then this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int t = 1; t <= 15; t++) {
        System.out.printf("series term %s = %,d\n", t, getSeriesValue(t));
    }

    System.out.println();

    int[] closetTo = {1, 2, 9, 10, 27, 33, 49, 52, 86, 100, 101, 499, 500, 510, 888, 1000, 1001, 4999, 5000, 5010, 9999, 10000, 12345, 49999, 50000, 99999, 100000, 102000, 500000, 750000, 1000000};
    Arrays.stream(closetTo)
            .forEach(x -> System.out.printf("%,d : %,d\n", x, getClosestSeriesValueLessThanOrEqualTo(x)));
}
```

gives output:

```
series term 1 = 1
series term 2 = 5
series term 3 = 10
series term 4 = 50
series term 5 = 100
series term 6 = 500
series term 7 = 1,000
series term 8 = 5,000
series term 9 = 10,000
series term 10 = 50,000
series term 11 = 100,000
series term 12 = 500,000
series term 13 = 1,000,000
series term 14 = 5,000,000
series term 15 = 10,000,000

1 : 1
2 : 1
9 : 5
10 : 10
27 : 10
33 : 10
49 : 10
52 : 50
86 : 50
100 : 100
101 : 100
499 : 100
500 : 500
510 : 500
888 : 500
1,000 : 1,000
1,001 : 1,000
4,999 : 1,000
5,000 : 5,000
5,010 : 5,000
9,999 : 5,000
10,000 : 10,000
12,345 : 10,000
49,999 : 10,000
50,000 : 50,000
99,999 : 50,000
100,000 : 100,000
102,000 : 100,000
500,000 : 500,000
750,000 : 500,000
1,000,000 : 1,000,000
```

The series quickly overflows `int` and `long`, so should probably adapt to use `BigInt`.